# How do I view Script Properties in the new Google Apps Script IDE

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

I've been switched over to the new Google Apps Script IDE.  I used to be able to click `FILE > PROJECT PROPERTIES` to access global properties for files

I cannot for the life of me find how you get there now??

anyone know?

p.s I can switch back to legacy for now but no good once this is removed....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This feature has already been reported in the [issue tracker](http://%E2%AD%90) as a future request:

[image]

### Star ⭐ the request and make it more visible.

Apparently, the google developer replied the following:

> Unfortunately, even though I couldn't find the script properties
> either, this is a feature related to the new editor rather than
> directly to Apps Script functionallities or its API.
>
> Therefore, the right place to file this feature request is on the top
> right question mark button of the editor and then selecting Send
> feedback as this will send your feature request to the right team.

Hopefully it will be resolved soon but you can increase its popularity by clicking on the start button.

### Workaround until the issue is resolved:

Access the project properties via the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) class:

`console.log(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties());`

Comment: Please @soMario fix the issue tracker link.

Comment: An issue such as this was filed January 2021 and marked as "Won't Fix / Unfeasible": https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177770837

Comment: How does one set the properties so they can be retrieved with the PropertiesService?  Using the GUI in the legacy editor sort of works, but when you re-open it, the properties you set previously are gone.

Answer (score 3):

#### April 13, 2022

From the report of ["Additional functionality for the Apps Script Integrated Development Environment (IDE) Script Editor"](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/04/apps-script-integrated-development-enviornment-improvements.html) and [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/#april_13_2022) on April 13, 2022, finally, Script Properties can be managed on new IDE.

[image]

The official document is as follows. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#manage_script_properties_manually

> You can manually add up to fifty custom properties, as strings in key-value pairs, from the project settings page. To add more than fifty properties, you need to add them programmatically using the methods described above in [Saving data](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#saving-data). When you set script properties from the project settings page, you can’t reference script variables.

#### Note:

- Today, I confirmed that Script Properties got to be able to be managed with a gmail account. So, I posted this.

Answer (score 2):

I had faced the same problem while adjusting the time zone in the Apps Script new editor. The easiest way I found was to click on `Use Legacy editor` on the top right corner of the new editor. Then I retrieved the legacy File menu. After setting the time zone, I clicked `Use new editor`. Setting was maintained when I returned back to the new editor.

How it looks in the new editor:
[image: How it looks in the new editor]

How it looks in the Legacy editor:

[image: How it looks in the Legacy editor]

Answer (score 1):

To see, change or delete Script properties, the most reliable way to do that is to write some code that uses Properties Service.

For example, you can log Script Property values as follows:

```
function getAllScriptProps() {

  var v = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  Logger.log(v)
}
```

You can continue to use the legacy editor to view and manage Script Properties, but the UI has always had bugs in it.
It will display Script Properties, but it doesn't always update or delete properties correctly.

Script Properties are part of Properties Service, which is separate from the Apps Script API.  Properties can be tied to a user, a document, or the Apps Script project file.  Even though the Apps Script API is for accessing Apps Script files, it has no way to list or update Script Properties.

The capabilities of the new IDE seem to be closely related to what the Apps Script API can access.

If they do decide to allow the new IDE permission to access your Script Properties, and add a UI to manage them, it would probably be announced in the release notes.

[Apps Script Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/)

I'm guessing that the legacy editor will eventually be deprecated, and if a new UI to manage Script Properties does not get implemented, then you'll need to use code.